# Is there any way to change the color of the text in vs code terminal to white?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

[image]

Why does my text color of the visual studio code terminal i.e. PowerShell is yellow and in other colors it is  annoying me is there any way to change the text color

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#integrated-terminal-colors

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as the solution if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Override **Terminal** colors

- In the **File** menu, navigate to **Preferences** and select **Settings**.
- In **Search Settings** box, enter **workbench.colorCustomizations**
- **Click** on **Edit in settings.json**
- Add the two hash values in the {…} section

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.background": "#012456",
    "terminal.foreground": "#ececec"
}
```